Why upcasted variable use virtual function from derived class C++
I have code something like that:
class Person
{
public:
    Person(const std::string& name, std::size_t age);

    virtual void print() const;
    void inc_age() { ++_age; }

private:
    std::string _name;
    std::size_t _age;
};

class Employee : public Person
{
public:
    Employee(const std::string& name, std::size_t age, double salary);

    virtual void print() const override;
    void add_bonus(double percent);

private:
    double _salary;
};


main is:
int main()
{
    Person mike{"Mike"s, 20};
    Employee manager{"Sam"s, 35, 100};

    Person* p{&manager};
    if (p) p->print(); // this line
    std::cout << '\n';

    return 0;
}


It's obvious now that I got it wrong, but as I realise line in main with comment
should use Person::print() because of implicit upcasting. But even using staic_cast<Person*>(p)->print() invoke Employee::print().
It's just academic interest (I'm a CS student) but how to make it use Person::print() without slicing (is slicing UB?)?
Another question is that: Our professor has said that if class isn't polymorphic (has no virtual functions) dynamic_cast happily runs without any error, silently producing UB. Is it correct and is there a way to prevent this?
P.S. Sorry for my poor English and poor knowledge of C++. I'm learning both quite some time but haven't become proficient in either yet.

That's the whole point of virtual functions -- they call the method from the actual type, not the declared type. This is how polymorphism is done.

This allows you to create an array of pointers to Person, fill it with different subclasses, and when you call the method on each element it calls the appropriate method for its type.

@Barmar so what is the point of upcast anyway?

When you have a virtual function and you call that through a base class pointer, it'll call the function overriding it in the most derived class. Don't make it virtual if you don't want virtual dispatch.

It allows you to write generic code that works with any type of Person.

Any good tutorial on OOP should explain these concepts.

@ProMike -- "upcast" and "downcast" are often confusing, but here, they're not needed because there are no casts in this code. A cast is something you write in your source code to tell the compiler to do a conversion. In your code there's an implicit conversion (no cast needed) that converts &Manager (whose type is pointer-to-Employee) to a pointer-to-Person.

Incidentally, that if(p) isn't needed. &Manager is a non-null pointer, and you won't get a null pointer from the conversion that's done there.

so what is the point of upcast anyway? Well, you can have std::vector<Person*> and put Employees or any other type of Person in there. You won't be able to add_bonus, but you will be able to print any of them. Or you can have a function that takes const Person& as argument and you can pass Employee in there.

@Yksisarvinen after all these explanations it's clear that I got the concept of upcasting wrong. I thought that it's something like 'explicitly made slicing' which left only the base part of object. And I know that we can use base class pointer to put base and derived classes to containers and treat them uniformly, but I didn't know that it is upcasting.

"I thought that it's something like 'explicitly made slicing'" Depending on the form of cast you use. static_cast<Person>(manager) is explicit slicing (and involves a copy), static_cast<Person&>(manager) and static_cast<Person*>(p) are upcasting without slicing or copying, dynamic_cast<Person&>(manager) and dynamic_cast<Person*>(p) are also upcasting without slicing or copying but is considered "code smell" and you should use implicit conversion or static_cast instead of dynamic_cast in this case. dynamic_cast<Person>(manager) is ill-formed (cannot compile).

@Weijun Zhou is slicing UB?

No. Slicing is not UB, but if you have never heard about "slicing", the result may be surprising, as the answer states. You may refer to this question for more details. Anyway, the language spec does not define "object slicing", it is the natural outcome of other C++ language rules.

The whole point of virtual functions is that you call the most derived class function even if you only have pointer to base class. If you want to call base class function directly, you have to spell it out:
manager.Person::print()

or
p->Person::print()



is slicing UB?

No, it's perfectly well defined. But the behaviour of slicing may be unexpected if you don't know about it, and I can't think of any situation where you actually want to invoke it.


Our professor has said that if class isn't polymorphic (has no virtual functions) dynamic_cast happily runs without any error, silently producing UB

True if you want to downcast (cast a Base pointer/reference to Derived pointer/reference), however, upcasting (from Derived to Base) is perfectly fine for any types (and can be done by static_cast as well or implicitly as you have done in your code).
